# Проверка входных данных при инициализации полей класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор, обработка-ошибок

Есть класс `Goods`

```
class Goods
{
private:
    double price, percent;
    unsigned int count;
    std::string name;
};
```

Как в конструкторе проверять входные данные для полей? Если они допустимы то инициализировать, иначе вернуть ошибку в виде сообщения что объект не создан.

Пример:

```
Goods(double &price,double &percent,unsigned int &count,std::string &name)
{
if (price>0.0){this->price=price;}else{//}
if (percent>0&&percent<100){this->percent=percent;}else{//}
if (count<0){this->count=count;}else{//}
if (name.length()!=0){this->name=name;}else{//}
}
```

Comment: выбросить исключение?

Answer (score 7):

```
else throw ...
```

Для того исключения и существуют.

Нет, конечно, некоторые добавляют поле типа

```
bool ok;

... else ok = false;
```

а потом проверяют - нормальный ли объект получился, но это путь не C++, а улучшенного С :) Получается, вы все равно вы создаете объект - хоть и в неверном состоянии. А если забудете потом проверить?

А вот исключение даже если забудете перехватить - оно само о себе напомнит :)

Comment: Ну и можно сделать так, чтобы  инициализация прошла успешно при любых значениях.  Например  после   double d = abs(d);    d = int(d) % 100 + d - int(d);   d > 0 && d < 100 при любых исходных значениях

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, Любопытно, зачем это?

Comment: @NewView,  сам не знаю_а вдруг захочется реализовать так...:))